# Facebook Graph API: link to user's profile page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the Facebook Graph API.
I am learning to find out mutual friends of two users, and provide a link to their facebook profile page.
Websites like http://www.chess.com/ do that.

On reading up, I realized that Graph API 2.1 does not let developers get the user-id. 
Is it that websites like chess.com use older APIs? If not, how do they get the link to profile pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `link` property of the User object will still give a URL that goes to that user's profile